# Ajax split receive [object object]

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to retrieve the value of a select which has as value (id + quantity available).
this is my code in blade:

```
<select class="wine" id="">
      <option value="0" selected>--</option>
    @foreach ($wines as $w)
      <option class="wineselected" name="wineselected" value="{{$w->id_wine}}-{{$w->quantita}}">{{$w->wine->nome}} disponibilità: <span class="qty" value="{{$w->quantita}}" style="color: red">{{$w->quantita}}</span></option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

e questo è il mio codice jquery

```
    $('.wine').change(function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        let wineselected=$(this).val();
        let split=$(this).toString().split('-');

        console.log(split);

        let wineid=split[0];
        let qty=split[1];
        
        
        
        if (wineselected) {
            $('.tavolo').attr("hidden", false);
            $('.quantita').attr("hidden", false);
        }
        
        
    });
```

as an answer I get [object object]
while I expect [id + qty]

where am i wrong?

Comment: `$(this)` is a jQuery object.... what do you expect it to be? Did you mean `wineselected.split("-")`

Comment: thank you for your reply, problem solved